# How to collect requested URL from user subscribing through Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subscription

I'm using rails 3. My whole app is restricted to registered Users using Devise 2.2.

My requirement :
Being able to say "user wanted to display the item X (as in item/:id was the requested url)when he subscribed". Whenever possible it will tell what item of the app the user wanted to see when he registered.

Example : John click on the www.website/item/48 link, but he is not registered into the system. After devise redirected him to the devise login page, he registered and was redirected (standard devise behavior) to www.website/item/48. Later the admin of the site is able to see that user john@whatever.net created an account because he wanted to see item 48.

Currently devise is set up the most classical way, with a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in all of my controllers. The login/subscrition pages are similar to the defaults ones, except for design.

I have overided the default registration controller of devise :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    super
    logger.debug"--------------------------------"
    logger.debug session.inspect
    logger.debug params.inspect 
    logger.debug resource
    logger.debug"--------------------------------"
  end

  def create
    super
    logger.debug"-----------------------------------"
    logger.debug session.inspect
    logger.debug params.inspect 
    logger.debug resource.inspect
    logger.debug"-----------------------------"
  end
end
```

I have no clue on how to get the requested URL from Devise. I can see it in the session variable during the new action, but once in create i cannot find it.

How can i get and save the requested URL in the create action of Devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoulde override the `sign_up` method in your registrations controller like this:

```
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource))
  path = session["#{scope}_return_to"] || signed_in_root_path(scope)
  logger.debug("Requested path before sign up: #{path}")
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
end
```

You can of course change the logger.debug if you want to store it in some other way. The important part is `session["#{scope}_return_to"] || signed_in_root_path(scope)`.

This will return the same as `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` but without deleting the referrer path in the session.

Comment: It do what i want but apparently, it's reading #{scope}_return_to in session and immediately erase it. I either get the url or have the user not redirected to original URL after sign up. I need both, and on top of that, i need a perfectly working devise as i'll use different kind of users... :/ But your answer is getting me on the right path, i'll update

Answer (score 2):

Right, you can override `sign_up` method and get that url with the following code:

```
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  url = session["#{scope}_return_to"] # here is your url

  super
end
```

Comment: why is it better to do it in sign_up rather than in create?

Comment: well, I think you can do in create do. it's just an example of getting that return_to url :)